# Can the list of favorites be extended using a Data Extender?

Tags: tridion

We have a data extender that displays the Version number of each item in all list views. Clearly "Favorites" is different, since our data extender doesn't work there.

So, can we do a data extender for the Favorites list? If not, what's the alternative to add the version number information to the item for display in the list?

Comment: Processing a list of favorites should be not very different from any other list of items, since they all share a very similar structure (with a different name for the root element). Can you post the XML that you expect to process and the code that you are using to process it?

Comment: Hi Warner, we have proposed a dedicated Stack Exchange site for Tridion, would you consider committing? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=7XNO_dQBJoWNn9xqeeO2NA2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. The Favorites List can be extended through a DataExtender, similar to how most other data structures can be extended. Since favorites are meant to be shortcuts to other items in the Tridion Content Manager data model, they have the same properties available on them.

This is an example of a list of items in my Building Blocks folder:

```xml
<tcm:ListItems Managed="10682" ID="tcm:1-1-2" 
               xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Item ID="tcm:1-5-2" Title="Component Templates" Type="2" 
              Modified="2011-11-18T11:09:45" IsNew="false" Icon="T2L0P0" 
              IsPublished="false" Lock="0" IsShared="false" IsLocalized="false" 
              Trustee="tcm:0-0-0" Allow="269085696" Deny="96" Managed="10682" />
</tcm:ListItems>
```

This is an example of a FavoritesList:

```xml
<tcm:ListFavoriteItems xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0">
    <tcm:Item xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" 
        ID="cme:0-41336414110293-shortcut" Title="Folder" RefID="tcm:1-57-2" 
        Path="\Content Management\Pub1\Building Blocks\Folder" Icon="T2" 
        Created="2012-5-7T14:8:30" HasChildren="false" Allow="24576" />
</tcm:ListFavoriteItems>
```

So aside from the root element name, this looks pretty similar to other lists you can get back from Tridion in your DataExtender.

Comment: that's good to hear, however I'm not getting it to work. if you can point out the error of my ways, that'd be great. I've got a class which extends DataExtender and works for other list views. But, when I intercept the command "GetListUserFavorites" I don't seem to get XML like I do with the other commands. is there anything different I should be doing?

Comment: I suggest you give more information about what you do. Specifically share a minimal code sample showing your problem.

Comment: I've got 5 items in my favorites. let me try again and I'll post the code if it doesn't work.

Comment: okay... got it working. comedy of errors. In the data extender we were using, we were filtering based on the "type" of item. the favorites XML doesn't have that. so, that block of code didn't work. then my code to dump out the entire XML that I got just didn't work. still don't know why, but removing the check for "type" solves the problem with my first block of code. now I'm able to use the RefID to go get the item it refers to and fetch its version info. thanks for the help. the XML snippet helped.

Comment: You're welcome Warner. Is there any way we can clean up this comment thread and improve the original question and answer?